# Picasso displays in wrong orientation

Tags: android, picasso, image-caching

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(lPreviewData.getImage()).into(holder.lPreviewIV);
```

This is how I am rendering the image url to ImageView. Unfortunately when i render an image it was showing in landscape mode but the actual image is in portrait.

Comment: share Image Url and screen shot

Comment: The actual image is : https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/images.sb.a-cti.com/full_spectrum/yeswanth.sreeramulu@a-cti.com/feeds/attachedFiles/L2FwcGhvc3RpbmdfcHJvZC9ibG9icy9BRW5CMlVwMm5KbTBNcC1Sd0NFeG14bW5qcTN4NGlUTTB4Q1NQZVk5VXQxcVQ0dklQRjhfaWRDSXAwZFdmZjgyNXFGNUVLMU1fT2ZPYVkwaTRZYzVYSEdvc3Q5cmY1QUlyUS5TSFZQc1dXZ1Q3aVNVMDJR

Comment: share your code of layout and imageview

Comment: Picasso showing like : https://postimg.org/image/j8cgc9q13/

Comment: Layout 

 <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/feed_image_iv1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="125dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

   Picasso code I already added on top

Comment: try this android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: No, it comes same with bigger height

Answer (score 2):

This is a [problem with exif rotation handling in Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/846). You should either rotate the image in code or fix the source image to have the correct orientation without using exif rotation.

I should also mention that this problem only affects images retrieved via url.

Comment: This should be fixed in the latest snapshot version.

Comment: which one is the latest snapshot version ?